# page curl/turn animation with editable fields android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I am trying to create page turn effects with multiple fragment/layouts and I have searched on internet for page turn animation, but I can find only page turn and curl effects with images or layout converted into bitmap.

I have tried these links:

http://developer.digitalaria.com/devguide/gama/en/gama/pageflip_android.php

https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl

Can we curl/turn page with editable field?

Please help
Thanks.